# Why does mailx see 0 messages in my mbox file?

Tags: mailx

I have an MBOX file created by dragging a folder from Outlook (For Mac v.16) into Finder (because the Export wizard in Outlook For Mac only generates OLM files).

I can look at the MBOX contents as plain text, and it looks sane.  I would like to verify the number of messages contained.  But mailx doesn't seem to see any messages:

`% mailx -f archive.mbox
Mail version 8.1 6/6/93.  Type ? for help.
"archive.mbox": 0 messages
? f
No applicable messages
? h
No applicable messages
?`

I realize it's a very old version of mailx, but that is what shipped with the Mac.

How does mailx expect messages to be delimited in the MBOX file?  Could I fix this with a simple find-replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that `mailx` objects to DOS linefeeds or some other problem with the export from Outlook. The format should otherwise be very simple; records start with a "From " line which is followed by the message headers, a blank line, and then the message body and I think another blank line before the next "From " record. So to count the number of records

```
grep -c '^From ' archive.mbox
```

should suffice, as that pattern may not appear in a message body (this is why you may see "From" in messages prefixed with some character when using mailbox files).

There are other tools that can parse mailbox files e.g. [Mail::Box](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Mail-Box/lib/Mail/Box-Cookbook.pod) (which I have not used) that might have better error messages than `mailx`.

Comment: Thanks!  You are right.  Replacing carriage returns with newlines fixed it.  In my case, `sed $'s/\\\r/\\\n/g' archive.mbox > fixed-archive.mbox`